# Geometric meaning of the vector triple product $(\vec a \times \vec b)\times \vec c$

Tags: vectors

Is their any geometric interpreatation to the vector triple product?

$(\vec a \times \vec b)\times \vec c$

For example the scalar triple product measures the area of the parallelopiped formed by the 3 vectors and the vector product (of 2 vectors) measures the area of the parallelogram formed by them.

Comment: Vector triple product, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product

Answer (score 2):

It's a vector in the plane spanned by $a$ and $b$ that is also perpendicular to $c$. I don't think that the magnitude maps to anything especially interesting for vectors. The place that I usually see this sort of construct, by the way, is when some of the "vectors" are a gradient operators $\nabla$.  In that case, it's a differential operator rather than a vector operation but, with care (and taking more of a physicist's view than a mathematician's), you can use many of the same identities. In the differential operator case, you can extract some geometric meaning about changes in vector fields in different directions, e.g. "curls of curls," which arise in some calculations with electromagnetic fields.